# Detect click on browser refresh button for all modern browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don´t really find an answer of my question, if it´s possible to detect by jquery if a user klick on the "Refresh/Reload Button" on a modern browser?

I found ...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    // Action
};
```

... but the problem at this way is, that it always fires if the page gets loaded. But if I use the forward button and then the back button it should **not** do this, only at pressing the refresh button. Is that possible? And is there a solution for all modern browsers?

**Edit:**
Thx for the link, I will try the cookie example.

Comment: AFAIK, no, there is no way to detect specifically the click on refresh button. Maybe you could explain why you would need that?!

Comment: I have some input fields (dropdown) which are cached by the browser on refresh and that makes an error at my script - but thx for the link, I will try it!

Comment: So instead, ask question regarding this error, not the workaround you think would fix it.

Comment: How about checking if the page refreshed (after) it refreshes..

Answer (score -2):

```
window.onunload = function(){
  alert("unload event detected!");
}
```

Onload fires before window refreshes actually.

or for key detection

```
$("body").keydown(function (e)
    {
   if (e.which == 116 || e.which == 17) {
     inFormOrLink = true;
   }
});
```

Comment: This is pressing F5 on keyboard. OP asking for the refresh button in browser.